# SQL Time difference between TIMESTAMP and TIME columns

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 columns on SQL table one of them has a data type of TIMESTAMP and the other has a data type of TIME i want to find the time difference between these 2 columns. This is how my table looks.

[image: Table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't subtraction work?

```
select sign_out - time(reg_time)
```

Note;  This assumes that the times are on the same day (which seems reasonable in this scenario).